# NLTK and stopwords Lookuperror in C# application

Tags: c#, python, nltk, sentiment-analysis, stop-words

I am running a python script from a C# application. The script runs fine on command prompt/terminal but fails to execute when invoked via C# code.

It says `Resource u'corpora/stopwords' not found.  Please use the NLTK Downloader to obtain the resource:  >>> nltk.download()` even though I have all the required data/stopwords

**Below is the error report from debug tab in Visual Studios.**

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Amey\Anaconda3\envs\dato-env\TrainingSetsUtil.py", line 20, in <module>
    stopwords = set(stopwords.words('english'))
  File "C:\Users\Amey\Anaconda3\envs\dato-env\lib\site-packages\nltk\corpus\util.py", line 99, in __getattr__
    self.__load()
  File "C:\Users\Amey\Anaconda3\envs\dato-env\lib\site-packages\nltk\corpus\util.py", line 64, in __load
    except LookupError: raise e
LookupError: 
**********************************************************************
  Resource u'corpora/stopwords' not found.  Please use the NLTK
  Downloader to obtain the resource:  >>> nltk.download()
  Searched in:
    - 'nltk_data'
**********************************************************************
```

**Here's the invoking code.**

```
ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();
        start.FileName = @"C:\Users\Amey\Anaconda3\envs\dato-env\python.exe";
        start.Arguments = @"C:\Users\Amey\Anaconda3\envs\dato-env\TrainingSetsUtil.py " + uname;
        start.UseShellExecute = false;// Do not use OS shell
        start.CreateNoWindow = true; // We don't need new window
        start.RedirectStandardOutput = true;// Any output, generated by application will be redirected back
        start.RedirectStandardError = true; // Any error in standard output will be redirected back (for example exceptions)
        using (Process process = Process.Start(start))
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput)
            {
                string stderr = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd(); // Here are the exceptions from our Python script
                string result = reader.ReadToEnd(); // Here is the result of StdOut(for example: print "test")
                Console.WriteLine(result);
                Console.WriteLine(stderr);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Have you run `nltk.download()` by hand after installation?

Comment: No. Actually, I just found a way to solve the problem. The main issue between C# and Python was the relative path to stopwords data which I find anomalous because the script runs fine on cmd prompt and have no issues with relative paths. To solve it, I imported stopwords from a text file instead of the NLTK data and changed some more path values.